# How to Login to a Server using Jmeter, MongoDb Config

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am Using the MongoDb Source Config and i want to hit a database on a server 10.X.X.X. This Server requires authentication. How can i do this authentication from Jmeter using MongoDb Config.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it by using MongoClient Class. Put following jar file "mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar" in Jmeter library folder and write following line of code in your JSR223 sampler selecting java as a language

```
      import com.mongodb.*;
      import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;
      import com.mongodb.DBObject;
      import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
      import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
      import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
      import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
      import java.util.*;
      import java.util.Arrays;
      import java.util.List;

      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("server 
      address:port"));
      DB db = mongoClient.getDB("database name");  
      db.authenticate("uname","password".toCharArray());
      DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("collection name");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) guide it should be something like:

```
DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("mongodb_source_name", "database_name", "username", "password");
```

So you don't to have to put anything into the MongoDB Source Config, credentials should be set in [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

To get MongoDB test plan "skeleton" you can utilise the relevant JMeter template:

```
File -> Templates -> MongoDB Load Test -> Create
```

[image: MongoDB Load Test JMeter]

Comment: thank for the reply, so you mean to say here:DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("mongodb_source_name", "database_name", "username", "password"); the username and password should be of the server?

Comment: Of the MongoDB instance

Comment: How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter  : this article doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try these here:

1. Download and install the mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar library from the [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver).
2. Place the library with the replacement of the old along the path
   "jmeter \ lib".
3. Using the JSR223 sampler, where Groovy is set as the language

Full text code:

```
import com.mongodb.*

MongoCredential coreCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("${userDB}", "${adminDB}", "${password}".toCharArray());
//we register connection options <user>, <database>, <password>. Admin Database is the main database. By logging in, you can read and edit all other databases.

MongoClient coreMongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("${server_mongoDB}", ${port_mongoDB}), Arrays.asList(coreCredential));
//we register the address and port of connection of the MongoDB server

DB coreDB = coreMongoClient.getDB("${mongoDb}");
//write the name of the database to which you are connecting

DBCollection coll = coreDB.getCollection("${collection}");
//write the name of the collection that you want to get

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
//we create object of future request

query.put(${key}, ${value});
//we create request. Search field format (key, value)

BasicDBObject s = coll.find(query).toArray();
//we carry out request

SampleResult.setResponseData(s.toString(),"UTF-8");
//output in response data so that you can use assert



//query option to select all collection entries in the response window
//SampleResult.setResponseData(coll.find().toArray().toString(),"UTF-8");
```